# javascript for loop with async function

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, promise, ecmascript-next

On the last line, the `getElementsByClassName` can't find element, because the `loadhtml` function is an AJAX call.

How to use async functions or ES6 generator or promise, in order to make the `getElementsByClassName` at the last line work?

```
    TotalArticleNumber = 3;

    for (let i = TotalArticleNumber; i > 0; i--) {
      loadhtml('./article/test' + i + '.md', function(e) {
        sdf(i, e);
      });
    };


    function loadhtml(url,callback) {
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if( xhttp.status == 200){
         var response = xhttp.responseText;
         (callback)(response);
        }
       };
     };

      xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
      xhttp.send();
    };



    function sdf(i, e) {
      var node = document.createElement("DIV");
      var node1 = document.createElement("A");
      var node2 = document.createElement("H1");
      var node3 = document.createElement("P");

      node.setAttribute('class', 'articleInner');
      node1.setAttribute('class', 'openArticle');
      node2.setAttribute('class', 'title');
      node2.setAttribute('id', i);
      node2.innerHTML = e.match(re);
      node3.innerHTML = converter.makeHtml(e.replace(re1, ""));
      node1.appendChild(node2);
      node1.appendChild(node3);
      node.appendChild(node1);

      document.getElementById('articleContent').appendChild(node);
    }

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('title'), function(item) {
      item.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('realArticle').style.display = 'block';
        document.body.style.background = 'gray';
      })
    })
```

Comment: You need to promisify the loadhtml function or build it on top of `fetch`.

Comment: Can you add the code for `loadhtml`?

Comment: Why don't you simply add the event handler to `node2`? You don't need any `getElementsByClassName` selection, and you don't need to time it after all elements are created.

Comment: I know it,just want to try some async function.

Comment: `async/await` is not part of ES7.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this use `async` features, you need to wrap the core of this in an `async function` block and use the `await` keyword for each promise you use:

Assuming `loadHtml` is an async function, you can use this:

```
function loadHTML(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
                var response = xhttp.responseText;
                if (xhttp.status == 200) {
                    resolve(response);
                } else {
                    reject(response)
                }
            };
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xhttp.send();
    })
};
async function loadHtmlAndMakeElements(){
    TotalArticleNumber = 3;
    let promises = []
    for (let i = TotalArticleNumber; i > 0; i--) {
        promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            loadHTML(`./article/test${i}.md`).then(e => {
                sdf(i, e);
                resolve()
            });
        }))
    }
    await Promise.all(promises);
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('title'), function(item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('realArticle').style.display = 'block';
            document.body.style.background = 'gray';
        })
    })
}
function sdf(i, e) {
    var node = document.createElement("DIV");
    var node1 = document.createElement("A");
    var node2 = document.createElement("H1");
    var node3 = document.createElement("P");
    node.setAttribute('class', 'articleInner');
    node1.setAttribute('class', 'openArticle');
    node2.setAttribute('class', 'title');
    node2.setAttribute('id', i);
    node2.innerHTML = e.match(re);
    node3.innerHTML = converter.makeHtml(e.replace(re1, ""));
    node1.appendChild(node2);
    node1.appendChild(node3);
    node.appendChild(node1);
    document.getElementById('articleContent').appendChild(node);
}
loadHtmlAndMakeElements()
```

Comment: Why the `return Promise.resolve()`? Also, the inner function with the callback isn't async, you can't do that ...

Comment: It says unexpected token at   `await sdf(i, e)`

Comment: Look like it still not gets the elements.

Comment: @Quill: No. It's an async function, so it *does* return a promise when called regardless what you `return`. Just drop that statement.

Comment: The original code loads data in parallel, yours sequentially.

Comment: @zeroflagL the OP is asking how to make his code load sequentially

Comment: Please, be so kind and show me the place in the OP's question where he expresses his wish to load the articles sequentially. The only requirement I see is _"How to use ES7 async function or ES6 generator or promise, in order to make the ... the last line work"_.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117314/discussion-between-zeroflagl-and-quill).